# Searching for the maximum number in MySql and then excluding it on a new search for the maximum number

Tags: c#, mysql

I have numbers in a MySql table, for example:

1. 129 | Kost
2. 28 | Alex
3. 98 | Nastya
4. 86 | Liza
5. 16 | Vika

It should go: 1,3,4,2,5.

I need to take a login that has a max number, then when a button is pressed in the application, I need another login to be taken from the list, already with a prior max number, which will disregard the max number already used, and then the button is pressed again...

I wrote an array in C# that adds a numeric string id, but I don't know how it can be used in a MySQL query to exclude it.

How can this be implemented properly?

Pulling all the strings to compare directly in the code won't work, there are too many of them.

Adding id to an array

```
dontSearchUser[value] = tgUserName;
value++;
```

Query in MySql. This finds the maximum number, but how to make the past found max number excluded?

```
static void SearchMaxComplaintUser()
        {
            DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tg_username FROM users WHERE numberСomplaints = ( SELECT MAX(numberСomplaints) FROM users );", dataBase.getConnection());

            dataBase.openConnection();
            tgUserName = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            dataBase.closedConnection();
        }
```

Comment: You need to find the second highest?

Comment: (1) Could the numberComplaints value in the database change between two presses of the button ? 
(2) Could the numberComplaints be the same for more than one tg_username ?

Comment: This looks like common sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to fetch users one at a time in order of how many complaints they have made. So really you need a function that will give you the nth user in order of number of complaints. You can do this with ordering by the number of complaints and then using mysql's `LIMIT` clause.

```sql
SELECT tg_username 
FROM users 
ORDER BY numberComplaints DESC
LIMIT @skip, @numrows
```

Where `@skip` is how many rows you want to skip. And `@numrows` is the number of rows to be returned. Note if you set `@numrows` to 1 it will return 1 row.

Here is a link to mysql's documentation on the `SELECT` statement. Ctrl-F search for `LIMIT` to read more about the syntax and use cases of that clause.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

You can add parameters in C#:

```cs
int skip = ...;
int numrows = ...;
MySqlCommand cmd = ...;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skip", skip);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numrows", numrows);
```